# Kohana 3.2 Call to undefined method Database_MySQL_Result::offset()

Tags: database, kohana

That happens when I try to play around with DB::select instead of ORM. 
The query is returned as an object, but the error appears.

Code:

```
$bd_userdata -> offset($pagination -> offset) -> limit($pagination -> items_per_page) -> find_all() -> as_array();
```

Error:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Database_MySQL_Result::offset()
```

Does it mean I have to count rows, before I send them to the offset in pagination?

---

When I try `$query->count_all()` I get the error message:

Undefined property: Database_Query_Builder_Select::$count_all

I tried `count($query)` but instead I got:

No tables used [ SELECT * LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0 ]

---

Here is the solution:

```
$results = DB::select('*')
->from('users')
->where('id', '=', 1)
->limit($pagination->items_per_page)
->offset($pagination->offset)->execute();
```

And a counter:

```
$count = $results->count_all();
```

I was doing it before, the other way around. That is why it did not work.

Comment: What type is `$bd_userdata`?

Comment: That was just simple: DB::select()->from('users')->where('username', '=', 'test')->execute();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, `execute()` returns `Database_Result` object, which has no QBuilder's functionality. You must apply all conditions (where, limit, offset etc) **before** calling `execute`.

Here is a simple example with pagination:

```
// dont forget to apply reset(FALSE)!
$query = DB::select()->from('users')->where('username', '=', 'test')->reset(FALSE);
// counting rows
$row_count = $query->count_all();
// create pagination
$pagination = Pagination::factory(array(
        'items_per_page'    =>  4,
        'total_items'       =>  $row_count,
    ));
// select rows using pagination's limit&offset 
$users = $query->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->items_per_page)->execute();
```